# Create 2D map on which objects can be placed and move in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, tile

I am new to Java and I'm trying to make a 2D text-based game that internally consists of a world map on which objects can interact and move. However, I'm already confused at the very beginning. Let's say that I have a 3x3 map. Each tile then, is a value in a multidimensional array (e.g. the tile on coordinates [0][2]). However, each tile must be **an array of objects** (e.g. either a tile object (Forest, Ground, Desert) or an entity (Person, Rock, Duck)). It should be an array since each tile must at least contain one tile object (Forest, Ground, Desert) but can contain a theoretical infinite number of entities.

I tried and combined some of the answers here. Current idea is to make a superclass entity that has nothing but coordinates. When the entity is created (given some coordinates), the object is linked to the world map on that position (doesn't seem to work). The World Map is a multidimensional array that can hold Entities.

The entity isn't linked to the world map, and I can't figure out why. It's definitely going wrong in the Entity.java and the World.java files, but I'm still unsure how to set the position to the world map. **Note that I would need to set or change the position of the entity from the map later on, or remove the entity as a whole (including its position on the map).**

Comment: don't name your class `Map` that is super confusing as there is already `Map` defined as part of java collections

Comment: `world.mapArray[0][0] = tile;` Although I would not recommend exposing `mapArray` directly to the outside world

Comment: When do you place your objects into your map? -- Do it inside your for loop.

Comment: @redFIVE Thanks, didn't know. Eclipse didn't give me a warning - strangly enough. Post updated.

Comment: @Michael You mean you'd make the mapArray private and use a setter? I am still confused about why something as `private` is necessary... But I'll have to read up on that. Post updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your tile should be an entity. I think tile should encapsulate entities.Eg.

```
public class Tile {
    final int xPos,yPos;
    private String type;
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    public Tile(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        xPos = xPosition;
        yPos = yPosition;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void addEntity(Entity e){
        entities.add(e);
    }
    public void removeEntity(Entity e){
        entities.remove(e);
    }
}
```

Then the world class will contain entites:

```
public class World {
    Tile[][] coordinates;
    List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();

    // Creates an instance of a map with a user-defined size
    public World(int width, int height) {
        coordinates = new Tile[width][height];
        for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<height; j++){
                coordinates[i][j] = new Tile(i,j);
                tiles.add(coordinates[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity e){
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        coordinates[x][y].addEntity(e);
    }
    public void setTileType(int x, int y, String type){
        coordinates[x][y].setType(type);
    }
    public List<Tile> getTiles(){
        return new List<>(tiles);
    }

    public List<Entity> getEntities(){
       List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Tile[] row: coordinates){
           for(Tile tile: row){
               entities.addAll(tile.entities);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Then it would follow that your main method would look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creators
    World worldMap = new World(mapWidth, mapHeight);
    Character john = new Character("John", 0, 0);
    Character mary = new Character("Mary", 1, 4);
    worldMap.addEntity(john);
    worldMap.addEntity(mary);

    for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
        worldMap.setTileType(x, 5, "forest");
    }

    // Printing out info about character(s)
    //I think the world map should  have a list of characters.

    for (Character character : charList) {
        System.out.print(character+": " + character.getName() + "\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n"+charList.size() + " characters in play\n\n");
    List<Tile> tileList = worldMap.getTiles(); 
    // Printing out info about tile(s)
    for (Tile tile : tileList) {
        System.out.print(tile + " type: " + tile.getType() + "\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n"+tileList.size() + " tiles in play");
}
```

The reason why there are two #addEntity()s is because of how *I* think to answer the following predicament.

"I want to create a character john and add him to the world at position x,y."

Of course we will have

```
Character john = new Character("john", x, y);
```

Then, how do we add john to the World? I say, we just add him to the world, and let the world know what to do with the tiles and such.

```
world.addEntity(john);
```

John has a position, and the world can find the tile, and place john on the tile. The converse, which is more similar to what you have tried, would be to find the tile and add john directly.

```
world.coordinates[john.getX()][john.getY()].addEntity(john);
```

As you have shown in your example, this has some issues with index out of bounds exceptions, which you should handle. So the problem is, you need to know a lot about the structure of the tiles to add an Entity. Instead, let the world add the entity, because then it can handle all of the caveats one time and place the Entity at the correct tile.

Comment: Hm, I do like this approach. Basically what you're doing is creating a world map of a specific size, then fill it with tiles. Only later you'll assign tile types. You can then also add items to specific coordinates? I am confused though, how you implemented `addEntity()`. There's one in the World class and one in the Tile Class. How I see it, you call .addEntity to the world, which then passes this on to the required tile. So, in a sense you're adding the Entity to the tile. Correct? I think the confusing thing is that they have the same name!

Comment: I have updated my code yesterday evening, and added a bounty to give you guys some motivation :) I do like your approach a lot, though, so I might fiddle around a bit and see if I can solve all my problems with your approach. If you want, you can read through my updated post and see what you can add to your answer. Thanks in advance, and +1 for the idea you already had!

Comment: @BramVanroy Re *addEntity*. Yes it can seem a bit confusing, that is the importance of a good API. Ill add an explanation at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been looking at your code and there's some things I'm not sure about. As I've said I'm new to Java, so I might be completely wrong here: on line 4 of `World` I think you forgot a `>` in `new ArrayList<()`. Also the type `Entities` doesn't exist. This line altogether seems superfluous, because you're already defining it inside `Tile`, or am I wrong? Also, thanks for the update!

Comment: @BramVanroy good eye. Note the List<Entity> in World keeps track of all the entities in the world. The List<Entity> in the tile keeps track of the entities in _that tile_ only. I agree that the List<Entity> in the World class is a bit superfluous. You could just create that list when you need it.

Comment: Oh, right I was confused again. For my own sake I'm going to change the names to something like entitiesInWorld and entitiesOnTile. Would it make sense to write "add entity" like this? I'm just spitballing here, but it seems a good place to get a try-catch block going to check the coordinates to the size of the world, and also adding the element to the list of entities of the world. [ Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/40iPx0RN).

Comment: @BramVanroy That is good, instead of throwing and catching an exception in a void method, maybe you should have a boolean return type, and return if entity was successfully added.

Comment: Thanks, on it. One more question, but for that we'd might want to move to chat if that's okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95227/discussion-between-bram-vanroy-and-matt).

Comment: Even though the code didn't implement directly the things I needed, it did give me the first bricks to build on. Today I finished the core if the project and it wouldn't have been possible without this post. Therefore,  I award you this bounty. The final code will stay available on github.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply mistaking the *tile map* for the *world*. These are not identical concepts. The tile map describes the basic look of the world and maybe some basic properties (like walkable, impassable).

Its however not a *complete* description of the world. Anything that is not a tile needs to be modeled additionally. I can think of three workable concepts:

a.) Have an additional array for things occupying a tile location. This may work well if only one "thing" can occupy a specific location at any time.

b.) Instead of using a *tile array* use a *location array*. The difference is that you can model location to contain whatever you need, e.g. a tile plus a list of occupants for the location. Thats the OO variant of a.

c.) Have an independent data structure that keeps track of things existing in the world, e.g. a list of people. You need to model the location where something is as part of the state of the items that can populate the world, e.g. a person now has an additional x, y coordinate indicating their place in the world.

Whichever you chose, they all have their pros and cons, you can also use a hybrid, e.g. have a location map *and* a list of items. This combines the strengths of the two models (quick and simple checks of the surroundings of a location through the location map, as well as simple access to the entire world population through a list). Pick whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but let me answer your direct question and then maybe give you a couple of hints.
So if you want to assign the entity John to your top-left corner you can do it by: `world.mapArray[0][0] = john;`
Anyway it is a good practice to have accessor and mutator methods for your `Java beans/POJOs`. Having said this I would recommend you to make all your fields private and then. In this case your code will look like:

```
public class Map {
      private Entity[][] mapArray;

      // Creates an istance of a map with a user-defined size
      public Map(int width, int height) {
         mapArray = new Entity[width][height];
      }

      public void setEntityAt(Entity entity, int x, int y) {
         if (x < 0 || x > mapArray.length || y < 0 || y > mapArray[x].length) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect X or Y parameters");
         }
         mapArray[x][y] = entity;
      }
   }
```

I would recommend you not to keep the position of the entity as part of its context, because otherwise you'll have to update it every time you move it. This way you can have something like:

```
Map world = new Map(mapWidth, mapHeight);
Entity john = new Entity("John");
world.setEntityAt(john, 0, 0);
```

Last, but not least, if you try to compile your code you must know that you cannot have more than 1 public class in a Java file.
P.S. You can use `JUnit` for testing.

Comment: If you're still interested: I added a bounty and a lot of additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I try not to help people by telling them to think my way. It is often better to go where your intuition leads you. That being said, I would still say you should refactor your Map class, since you are not really wanting a java Map, and give it a different name, and here I suggest World as your class to contain your tiles. Also your Main class should be Game, with a main method. These changes I suggest only because Map and main have their own meaning in java.

You also need to separate your classes so each is in its own .java file. So what you started with, plus the above mentioned refactoring leaves three files:

```
    Entity.java
package stackoverflow;

public class Entity {
    String name;
    int xPosition, yPosition;

    // Creates an entity with a name, and an x/y-position on a maps
    public Entity(String name, int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;
    }
}

World.java
package stackoverflow;

public class World {

    Entity[][] mapArray;

    // Creates an istance of a map with a user-defined size
    public World(int width, int height) {
        mapArray = new Entity[width][height];
    }
}

Game.java
package stackoverflow;

public class Game {
    static int mapWidth = 8;
    static int mapHeight = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        World world = new World(mapWidth, mapHeight);
        Entity john = new Entity("John", 0, 0);
        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
                Entity tile = new Entity("Tile", x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The multi-dimensional array will work, but has some drawbacks. You could just as well make your world a List of Entity's to which you could add, remove, traverse, etc, possibly with more ease than the array. But you can get your feet wet using what you know for now. For testing, I suggest you add JUnit to your project. I also like to evangelize for test-driven development, but that is probably a whole different question.

To make your entities move, add a move(x, y) method or moveTo(x, y) method to your Entity object, with distance to move (or new coordinates) as parameters.